# MATCH function doesn't find equal cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm designing a datasheet that updates itself automatically. All of the macro code is working properly, but I have trouble locating the place where the data should be copied.

I'm using the function match to detect the index on a table like this:

```
=MATCH(Y4;DataBase[Time];0)
```

The match function is not returning any value, just `#N/A`. I've already tested it with some cells and when doing

```
=Cell1=Cell2
True
```

It returns a true value, confirming they're equal, but `=Match` doesn't seems to find them.

Link to the bit of datasheet that troubles me

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15JzT1xsQpO50dSvdYR-iouZ23w1toS4d/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112168268147918398104&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: But my guess is that one or the other is text that looks like time, while the other is a true time.

Comment: Both are date format and numbers

Comment: See previous post here: https://superuser.com/questions/1549376/excel-match-function-seems-to-be-broken-issue-description-and-investigation-det   In my testing I could confirm your observation, even after converting the dates to numeric values, the match failed, even when the numbers appear exactly the same (going out to Excel's limit of precision)